# hide and show component with angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am creating a web app in c# but i am using angularjs for fetching data from sql-server and there is one issue for me

as i am using angular for fetching the data I want to use angular for showing and hiding the required component

like there is a dropdownlist

```
<select>
<option>Guest</option>
<option>Google</option>
<option>User</option>
</select>
```

and i have 3 textboxes

```
<input type="text" visible="false" name="Guest">
<input type="text" visible="false" name="Google">
<input type="text" visible="false" name="User">
```

If a user select Guest from dropdownlist

`<input type="text" visible="false" name="Guest">`
this textbox should be visible

If a user select Google from dropdownlist

`<input type="text" visible="false" name="Google">`
this textbox should be visible

If a user select User from dropdownlist

`<input type="text" visible="false" name="User">`
this textbox should be visible

now I want to know how to hide or show these component in angularJS

Comment: which Angular version r u using ? angular 1.* or angular 2.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya i am using 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really interested to do it in angular way the set `ng-model` and `ng-show` first for all text controls.

```
<select ng-model="ddSelect" ng-change="getOptions()">
<option>Guest</option>
<option>Google</option>
<option>User</option>
</select>

<input type="text" visible="false" name="Guest" ng-model="txtGuest" ng-show="isGuestVisible">
<input type="text" visible="false" name="Google" ng-model="txtGoogle" ng-show="isGoogleVisible">
<input type="text" visible="false" name="User"  ng-model="txtUser" ng-show="isUserVisible">
```

Now in controller get hold of `getOptions`

```
$scope.isGuestVisible = false;
$scope.isGoogleVisible = false;
$scope.isUserVisible = false;

$scope.getOptions = function(){

if($scope.ddSelect === "Guest"){
    $scope.isGuestVisible = true;
    $scope.isGoogleVisible = false;
    $scope.isUserVisible = false;
}
}

//Likewise check other options and set ng-show.
```

Note: This solution is given based on your exact case study .It could be made more dynamic thus reducing if.

Comment: first option of my dropdown became blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#!) and [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directives. It would look like:

```
<select ng-model="selected">
    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
    ...
</select>
...
<input type="text" ng-show="selected === 'Guest'" name="Guest">
```